# SwiftUI: Expanding TextField size to font size before input

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having a problem with SwiftUI TextField. The cursor and text field size initially is very small, and on input it grows to the full size (in this case .largeTitle). I have made the background black so you can see what is happening to the actual field. Is there a way to set the size of the TextField so the cursor starts off the same size as the text? I have tried all the functions from the documentation with no luck... This is using Xcode 11 Beta 5. Thanks!

```
TextField("", text: input)
    .lineLimit(nil) // doesn't seem to work in Xcode 11 Beta 5
    .font(.largeTitle)
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .background(Color.black)
```

[image: gif of problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug where setting the style of textfield has no effect, unless the textfield has initial contents. Let's hope beta 6 fixes that. In the meantime, here's a workaround that works for me:

The textfield starts with a value, but resets immediately in the `.onAppear` closure, so you never actually see it:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var input = "x"

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $input)
        .lineLimit(nil) // doesn't seem to work in Xcode 11 Beta 5
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .background(Color.black)
        .onAppear { self.input = "" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know whether it was a beta bug or intended functionality. Thanks for the help, the work around works perfectly :)

Comment: This still isn't fixed in the Xcode 11 GM. Have you found any other way to fix this? Because even though this solution works for the first input, if you come back to an empty TextField, the bug occurs again...

Comment: EDIT: Just found out a way to solve that problem. Adding a space in the TextField placeholder stops the field from losing its size! Unfortunately the fix you gave is still required

Comment: the placeholder workaround works for me, but the caret size is wrong, did you find a way to fix that too?

Comment: I have put a placeholder there, but the cursor is still very small before I type anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Remains the same in beta 3